# Howto dynamically render space background in actionscript3?

Tags: actionscript-3, dynamic, flex3, background, rendering

I'm creating a space game in actionscript/flex 3 (flash). The world is infinitely big, because there are no maps. For this to work I need to dynamically (programatically) render the background, which has to look like open space.

To make the world feel real and to make certain places look different than others, I must be able to add filters such as colour differences and maybe even a misty kind of transformation - these would then be randomly added and changed.

The player is able to "scroll" the "map" by flying to the sides of the screen, so that a certain part of the world is only visible at once but the player is able to go anywhere. The scrolling works by moving all objects except for the player in the opposite direction, making it look like it was the player that moved into that direction. The background also needs to be moved, but has to be different on the new discovered terrain (dynamically created).

Now my question is how I would do something like this, what kind of things do I need to use and how do I implement them? Performance also needs to be taken into account, as many more objects will be in the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only have views for objects that are within the visible area. You might want to use a [quad tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quad_tree) for that.

The background should maybe be composed of a set of tiles, that you can repeat more or less randomly (do you really need a background, actually? wouldn't having some particles be enough?). Use the same technique here you use for the objects.

So in the end, you wind up having a model for objects and tiles or particles (that you would generate in the beginning). This way, you will only add a few floats (you can achieve additional performance, if you do not calculate positions of objects, that are FAR away. The quad tree should help you with that, but I think this shouldn't be necessary) If an object having a view leaves the stage, free the view, and use the quad tree to check, if new objects appear.

If you use a lot of objects/particles, consider using an [object pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool). If objects only move, and are not rotated/scaled, consider using `DisplayObject::cacheAsBitmap`.

Comment: Thanks again. I am using techniques to only load objects that are near, and objects that leave the visible area are unloaded aswell.

Could you please explain how to generate such a dynamic background?

Comment: I mean something like http://flashden.net/item/dust-particles-effect-background-animation/30399 - just that the background shouldn't move when the player stands still.